# Microsoft Web Administration System.IO.FileLoadException

Tags: c#, web, iis-8, administration

I am trying to create a new website in IIS using Microsoft Web Administration via C#.  Unfortunately I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException 
>         HResult=-2147024864
>         Message=Filename: \?\C:\Users\david\OneDrive\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config
>       Error: Cannot write configuration file

Any ideas to resolve this appreciated.

Original code here: https://johnlnelson.com/2014/06/15/the-microsoft-web-administration-namespace/

Comment: Try restart visual studio / IIS server / windows.

Comment: Do you have enough space on Disk ?

Comment: OneDrive might have locked the file, so that MWA cannot write to it. Use a file path outside of OneDrive controlled folders and try again.

Comment: I am a coder and not a server guy.  This is a project I'm working on alone.  So I need to look into 'using a path outside of OneDrive'

Comment: In the meantime anyone else come across this problem and can give detailed direction?